# "could not instantiate" NHibernate.QueryException Raise By Combined Linq Query

Tags: linq, nhibernate, iconvertible

Executing the following NHibernate.Linq statement raises a `"could not instantiate: Reservation001.Services.ReservationDto"` NHibernate.QueryException containing an inner InvalidCast exception ("Object must implement IConvertible."):

```
var inOneStep = (from r in session.Linq<Models.ReservationHeader>()
    select new ReservationDto(r.Current));
return inOneStep;
```

However, after splitting the above into two queries, with ToList() called on the results of the first, the code executes fine.

```
var step1 = (from r in session.Linq<Models.ReservationHeader>()
     select r).ToList();
var step2 = from z in step1
     select new ReservationDto(z.Current);
return step2;
```

Why does the single statement version raise an exception?

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the first one does not work is because the whole query is getting sent to NHibernate, and (as the exception tells you) NHibernate expects something with ReservationDto to be IConvertible.

The two step process avoids this error, because by calling "ToList()" you cause the query to execute in NHibernate immediately **without** involving ReservationDto, and returning an object collection.  Your second step is then simply operating on an object collection, and since NHibernate is no longer involved, you avoid the error.

In general, Linq uses delayed execution, with a few functions (such as ToList() ) forcing immediate evaluation. See http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/04/07/linq-and-delayed-execution.aspx

Comment: In the first example, why does ReservationDto need to be convertable? Is this a limitation of NHibernate's Linq implementation?

Comment: @Ben Gribaudo - The cast/IConvertible exception seems most likely to be a type mismatch in the mapping files, but it is hard to say for sure.  See for example: http://davidchristiansen.com/archive/2005/04/01/27953.aspx , http://forums.asp.net/t/1627881.aspx , https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2302650&sid=ff2dcb4c955af1b6eb7a29727402e2bd , https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=990532&start=0  Depending on your circumstances, you can either simply correct the mappings, or if appropriate, actually implement IConvertible.